# How to hide/ show navbar when user clicks on the bar icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I hide my navbar when the user clicks on the "bar-icon"?

I want to create a navbar which begins `hidden` and when the user clicks on the bar icon, the navbar `displays`

. Can you do that with `JavaScript`? Or do you need `jQuery` for that?

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
    <header class="header">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      <nav class="nav">
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="bannerContainer">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
nav {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <header class="header">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      <nav class="nav">
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="bannerContainer">
      <h1>Display like that above!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm just trying to figure out how I can hide the navbar, so no fancy-looking 3D effects when it displays is needed, (for now at least). 
If I haven't provided enough information, please tell me so that I can provide the right amount of information needed to solve this.

Comment: Jquery would be the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: You even can do it with pure css, no javascript: http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/

Comment: What in your question precludes a CSS-only solution?

Comment: @Krillgar It's just that the solution with JavaScript is less code, the CSS solution probably was 20+ lines of code.

Comment: @ChrisG Could you provide a solution with jQuery maybe? :)

Comment: How do you know that if you don't have a solution? Besides, number of lines of code isn't always a good metric of the quality of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to control that with a simple show and hide with basic javascript:

```
function openMenu(e){
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block';
}

function closeMenu(e){
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xo87kz6/

Answer (score 0):

You may use jQuery for this purpose. 
Make sure to include jQuery in your project.

**Jquery Part**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bar").click(function(){
        $(".bannerContainer").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML Part**

```css
nav {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <div id = "bar">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      <nav class="nav">
      </nav>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="bannerContainer">
      <h1>Display like that above!</h1>
    </div>
```